# Cómo hacer un select de fuentes para CSS

Tags: css, html-select, fuentes

Tengo una consulta.
Quiero hacer en mi panel un selector de las fuentes para que mi cliente pueda seleccionar que fuente usar en su sitio.
Para estoy usando un archivo `css` que creo con `PHP` donde guardo en una variable `CSS` el nombre de la fuente y lo recupero en el `css` de estilos con `font-family: var(--fuente_seleccionada);`

Hasta aquí todo bien.
Ahora lo que quiero hacer es un `select` donde aparezcan todas las fuentes con su previsualización de como es cada una para poder guardar el nombre de la misma en mi base de datos.

La consulta puntual es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer ese `select` ? O sea, ¿De dónde saco todos los nombres de las fuentes y cómo hago que cada una se vea como es la fuente realmente ?

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, lo que yo haría sería, 1. leer el archivo css como un texto y ubicar las variables font-family, y ya, con eso por medio de javascript cambio el body (fiont-family: tu-fuente). tambien se me ocurre que podrías crear diferentes archivos CSS con las fuentes diferentes en cada uno y segun el selector, cargar dichos archivos.

Comment: Es que ese no es el problema. El tema es que no se de donde sacar  todos los tipos de fuentes que se pueden utilizar en una web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te mostraré una solución que he encontrado a tú problema.

*PRIMERO*

Puedes sacar los tipos de fuente en Google Fonts que es un gran conjunto de estilos de letras que se pueden utilizar gratuitamente.

Entonces en tu archivo css harás esto.

```css
/* Estilo Roboto */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');

/*Estilo Inspiration */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inspiration&display=swap');

/* Estilo Poppins */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap');
```

*SEGUNDO*

Ya en tu *select* aplica el respectivo archivo CSS con las fuentes seleccionadas de Google Fonts.
Lo que viene a continuación es un truco para crear el estilo de un select únicamente con CSS.
¿Por qué digo que es un truco? Porque solo hay unos pocos atributos de estilo que se pueden aplicar a un elemento . Esto se debe a que este tipo de elemento es un ejemplo de un "elemento reemplazado". Dependen del sistema operativo y no forman parte del HTML/navegador. No se puede diseñar a través de CSS.

El Truco (Basado en el artículo de Carlos Cuba):

https://carloscuba014.medium.com/building-a-custom-select-field-without-any-javascript-25c0f10cad53

```css
/* Basado en el artículo de Carlos Cuba, https://carloscuba014.medium.com/building-a-custom-select-field-without-any-javascript-25c0f10cad53  */
/* Editado por Jack More */

/* Estilo Roboto */
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');

    /*Estilo Inspiration */
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inspiration&display=swap');

    /* Estilo Poppins */
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap');

    /* Estilo Poppins Sans Serif */
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900");

    /* Estilo Oswald */
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');

    /* Estilo Smokum */
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Smokum&display=swap');

#dropdown {
  border: 1px solid #00b456;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden; 
}
#dropdown option {
  
  background-color: white; 
  color: black;
  height:100%; 
  overflow:hidden; 
}
#dropdown option:nth-child(2) {
  
  margin-top:20px; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size:30px; 
}
#dropdown option:nth-child(3) {
 
  margin-top:20px; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "Roboto ";
  font-size:30px; 
}
#dropdown option:nth-child(4) {
  
  margin-top:20px; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
  height: 100px;
  
  font-family: "Inspiration";
  font-size:30px; 
}
#dropdown option:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top:20px; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size:30px; 
}
#dropdown option:nth-child(6) {
  margin-top:20px; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
  height: 100px;
  font-family:"Smokum"; 
  font-size:30px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>     

<body>



<div id='select-container'>
  <select id='dropdown'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>Estilos</option>
    <option>Poppins Sans-Serif</option>
    <option>Roboto</option>
    <option>Inspiration</option>
    <option>Oswald</option>
    <option>Smokum</option>
    
  </select>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este código lo he editado conforme a tu petición. El usuario puede ver los diferentes estilos de fuente y seleccionar la fuente que más quiera mediante un *select*.

Este truco tiene algunos contratiempos, por ejemplo no puedes editar el *width* ni el *height* de los `<option>`, no puedes poner márgenes o *paddings*.

Si te gustaría poder cambiar-los, entonces tendrías que utilizar `JavaScript`. Te dejo un link como referencia.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @JorgePiovano Porfavor si te ha ayudado marca la respuesta como correcta ( tick) marcando el tick verde y si te ha sido útil vótala positivamente.  Está acción ayudará a la comunidad y también a mí. Gracias a ti.